# How to get the difference between 2 times in hours and minutes using javascript .change function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The time are selected by the user, after the user have select both times, the duration checkbox should auto calculate the duration of the time and display the duration in the duration textarea. Please have a look on my code... Thank You. I have put an alert to test, and I still can't get the duration in the alert.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stime = document.querySelector("#FromTime"),
    etime = document.querySelector("#ToTime"),
    duration = document.querySelector("#duration");

  stime.onchange = etime.onchange = function() {
    if (!stime.value || !etime.value) {
      return;
    }
    var sTime = stime.value.split(":"),
      eTime = etime.value.split(":"),
      minutes = (eTime[0] * 60 + +eTime[1]) - (sTime[0] * 60 + +sTime[1]),
      hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    if (minutes < 1) {
      return duration.innerHTML = "The ending time must be bigger than the starting time";
    }
    duration.innerHTML = `Duration: ${hours} hours and ${minutes % 60} minutes`
  };

});
```

```html
<div class="input-field col m6 s12">
  <label for="FromTime">From Time : </label></br>
  </br>
  <input type="time" name="FromTime" id="FromTime" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>

<div class="input-field col m6 s12">
  <label for="ToTime">To Time : </label></br>
  </br>
  <input type="time" name="ToTime" id="ToTime" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <label for="duration" name="duration" id="duration">Duration (Hour): </label></br>
  </br>
  <input type="text" name="duration" id="duration" style="width:70px; height:35px;" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem please ?

Comment: The problem is the duration are not displayed after the time is selected

Comment: Do you mean that the calculation operates correctly but the result is not displayed ? Meaning this is an issue about changing the visible page component?

Answer (score 0):

Here I made this for you

```js
var stime = document.querySelector("#start-time"),
  etime = document.querySelector("#end-time"),
  duration = document.querySelector("p");

stime.onchange = etime.onchange = function() {
  if(!stime.value || !etime.value) {
    return;
  }
  var sTime = stime.value.split(":"),
    eTime = etime.value.split(":");
  eTime[0] = eTime[0] == 0 ? 12 : eTime[0] == 12 ? 24 : eTime[0];
  sTime[0] = sTime[0] == 0 ? 12 : sTime[0] == 12 ? 24 : sTime[0];
  var minutes = (eTime[0] * 60 + +eTime[1]) - (sTime[0] * 60 + +sTime[1]),
    hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
  if(minutes < 1) {
    duration.innerHTML = "";
    return alert("The ending time must be bigger than the starting time");
  }
  duration.innerHTML = `Duration: ${hours} hours and ${minutes % 60} minutes`
};
```

```html
<label>From time:</label>
<input type="time" id="start-time">
<label>To time:</label>
<input type="time" id="end-time">
<p></p>
```

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look, thank you

Comment: Okay I have edited my post to alert when the duration is invalid, try it out.

Comment: i have tried it, but it still doesn't work , I put the code in the script and $(document).ready(function(){      is that correct ??

Comment: Man look you need to put all of my code including HTML, or else it won't work at all, I have my own selectors, if you want to only use my script then you need to change the selectors, and it's your job to relate it with your HTML the way it should.

Comment: yes , i have already change the selector, I have change it to "#FromTime" , "#ToTime" and "#duration" same as my html but it still doesn't work. Please have a look at my code , I am scared that I  put the code in the wrong place

Comment: duration.innerHTML = `Duration: ${hours} hours and ${minutes % 60} minutes` change it to duration.value= `Duration: ${hours} hours and ${minutes % 60} minutes` since you are using input element and not a p element as I did

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few inconsistencies, Try the below, put the duration calculation into a single function and assign a var to the elements.

Plus you need to set the id to the duration INPUT element not the LABEL.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fromEl = document.getElementById('FromTime');
    var toEl = document.getElementById('ToTime');
    var durationEl = document.getElementById('duration');

    $(fromEl).change(function() {
        toEl.min = fromEl.value;
        updateDuration();
    })

    $(toEl).change(updateDuration);

    function updateDuration() {
        if (!fromEl.value || !toEl.value) return;

        var start = new Date (fromEl.value);
        var end = new Date (toEl.value);

        var durationInMilliseconds = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
        var durationInHours = durationInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60);
        durationEl.value = durationInHours + ' hours';
    }
});
```

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <label for="duration" name="duration" >Duration (Hour): </label></br></br>
    <input type="number" name="duration" id="duration" required>
</div>
```